# how to create bibtex for a paper that has been accepted to a conference but not yet published?

Tags: bibtex, thesis

My paper got accepted to an ICRA conference but it is yet to be published. I need to create a bibtex entry for the same so that I could refer to in my thesis. What is the format to do the same?

I found the following format for journal:

```
@unpublished{key,
author ={J Mentor},
title ={Behavior of small animals on fire},
journal ={Nature},
note ={(in press)}}
```

How to do the same for a conference?

Comment: The format that's expected for your thesis will depend on the specific formatting requirements for your institution. I would start with this as the template and then consult with your advisor about whether the bibliography entry needs to be modified in any way.